# javascript: href link not working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios-simulator

The following piece of code is working on Android devices and iPhone simulator but not working on the iPhone device.

```
<a style="color:#1cffff" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://somesite.com.');"><u>mysite_name</u></a>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<a style="color:#1cffff" href="http://somesite.com">mysite_name</a>
```

But none of them have worked. Please advise.

Comment: How exactly is the second example not working? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: its not working.i am able to click the link. its not redirecting to my page.the same code working good in android phones, and all browsers...

Comment: Post some more code. It's not working because you have some kind of prevented event bubbling.

Comment: just I am displaying the link inside a div. its very simple. not much code involved. Code is working fine fo all browsers and phones except iPhone. is there any other way for redirecting the user to mywebsite when they click on the link??

Comment: Is there anyone to slove this problm?????? give some ideas or other solutions for my problem

Comment: What you posted is perfectly valid HTML (even though a bad practice). You really should let us see your Javascript code. If the code is working fine everywhere except iPhone, then obviously iPhone's problem must be the Javascript code of yours.

Comment: @Dray Provide some of your javascript code

Comment: converted_str=converted_str.replace(converted_str.substring(href_index+8,qoutes_index+1),"\"#\"onclick=\"window.open('http://www.astroved.com"+link_string+"')\"");

this is my code...

Comment: the problem is not with the coding.i found the problem.It is , when i was clicking the link, its opening as a popup window. so it was blocked in iphone automatically. How to get out of this problem????

Comment: @Dray why are your links opening in a popup?

Comment: in the <a href> i didnt mention target="_self". once i included tat, my problem was solved. answer was given by Brandan.and its below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an HTML `<base>` tag in your document? Something like this:

```
<base href="http://somesite.com" target="_blank">
```

If so, all of your links will open in a separate window by default. You'll probably need to get rid of that element or explicitly set a target on links that you want to open in the same window:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com" target="_self">Link text</a>
```

Here are [some more details on the `<base>` element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base/target).

Comment: I am using <a href> only.. but i misses the " target="_self" ". and this helps me. :) :) thnks!!

Answer (score 1):

try this if you use webview

```
NSString *str =@"<a style='color:#1cffff' href='http://www.somesite.com'>www.somesite.com</a>",

[webview loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='background-color: transparent;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:13;color: rgb(65,75,86);'>%@</body></html>",str ] baseURL:nil];
```

not then use

```
<a href="javascript:yourFunction()">Some Link</a>
```

Comment: and i am using div to display the link.plz provide me some other idea to take user to my page when they click the link...

Comment: I am doing my project using javascript and html. your answer is based on objective C right. It will not help me. give me some solution in javascript..and thnks a lot for ur quick replys.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8167/discussion-between-elppa-and-dray)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this as an alternative solution

`<a href=”javascript:window.location.href=’http://google.de’”>Link</a>`

This has also a benefit in fullscreen webapps that you added to homescreen since it won't kick you out of the app, into safari but will load the href into the current webview.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<a style="color:#1cffff" href="http://somesite.com" target="_self">mysite_name</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know as you told you have tried everything there.

Okay so let me give you some hint regarding debugging tips.

I hope it may help you out. Just build the app for iPhone device and go to that build folder and open the app (show package and contents) and open your html file in safari and use the debug/development tool of safari browser or you may try in other brwoser for to just debug.